# HandsOnTable range filter on dates (add datepicker)

Tags: datepicker, handsontable

Adding filters to a handsontable is very easy. [See here](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.2.0/demo-filtering.html).

It also has a nice filter by condition "is between" and there you can put the 2 values:

[image]

The problem is that, despite having datepickers in the cells, we don't have datepickers here. Any idea on how to have datepickers also here?

I also wonder if the "is between" will really take the dates or their string representation to compare...

Thank you